Is strongly convex function always bounded below?
Is strongly convex function always bounded below?
If yes, can we prove it? Or could we construct an example if the answer is no?
I have tried to construct counterexamples such as the function $f(x) = x + e^x$, the function is unbounded below as $x\to-\infty$, $f(x) \to-\infty$, but the function is not strongly convex since $\nabla^2 f(x) = e^x $ doesn't satisfy that $\exists m >0, \forall x, \nabla^2 f(x)> m$.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

your definition does not match the standard one. The counterexample works for the correct definition.

What's wrong with the given counterexample?  $x + e^x$ has positive second derivative everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ so it is strictly convex, according to both the usual definition and the given definition.

sorry @daw and lily, I used the wrong terminology, what I want to ask is "Is strongly convex function always bounded below", "strongly convex function" is more strict than "strictly convex function". I edit the question description now.

Wikipedia says it does have minimum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions

Thanks @student91, your information is quite helpful!

Thanks @daw, I agree the question in the link you provided has included my question as a subcase. Then this post can be closed!

You should note that your definition in the question is not the same as "strongly convex" (even ignoring the question of twice-differentiability) because the quantifiers are swapped.

@lily, I didn't use the standard definition of strongly convex function, instead, a property  was used: If the function $f(x)$ is twice continuously differentiable, then $f(x)$ strongly convex if and only if $\nabla^2f(x)>m>0$  for all $x$.

Yes but the definition in your question is wrong.  $\exists m \forall x$ is not the same as $\forall x \exists m$

Thanks @lily! I revised it to $\exists m>0, \forall x, \nabla ^2f(x)>0$.
